# Dictionary autoarranging?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        if head == None:
            return None
        start = head
        prev = head.val
        a = {prev:1}
        #o = [prev]
        head = head.next
        while head != None:
            if head.val == prev:
                a[prev] += 1
            else:
                prev = head.val
                a[prev] = 1
                #o.append(prev)
            head = head.next
        b = ListNode(0)
        ans = b
        for i in a: # can use for i in o
            if a[i] == 1:
                c = ListNode(i)
                b.next = c
                b = b.next
        return ans.next
```

I am trying to remove duplicate items from a **sorted linked list**, eg.`[1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6]` -> `[1,2,5]`. Can someone walk through the code and tell me what will be the final value of `a` is for the linked list `2`->`1`->`None`. It should be `{2:1, 1:1}` but answer comes out to be `{1:1, 2:1}`...why?

Comment: Don't make needless classes. Solution is a totally useless class.

Comment: That was the format of the solution to be submitted on a website, ignore that.

Comment: Looks like some of that silly automated tests some companies use for hiring programmers.

Comment: Do you only want to remove adjacent duplicates? Is the linked list sorted prior to the removal of duplicates? What do you expect in the case of `[1, 2, 1]`?

Comment: So the question boils down to this: given a list `[1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6]` return another list with just the unique elements. Is this correct?

Comment: Is the list sorted already?

Comment: No no, you don't understand. It isn't our job to *ignore extraneous stuff*, it is *your job* to provide a [mcve]

Comment: But, fundamentally, your question: "{2:1,1:1} but answer comes out to be {1:1, 2:1}" doesn'tmake any sense: **those are equivalent dictionaries**. Python `dict` is *unordered*.

Comment: If order is important use `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score 2):

`dict` object doesn't remember the order of elements which are added to the dictionary. If you want to preserve the ordering of the elements you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

O(N) option using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [k for k,g in groupby([1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6]) if len(list(g)) == 1]
[1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: that requires the list to be sorted, though

Comment: Sure, but if I understand question, it is precondition.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6]
>>> [i for i in l if l.count(i) == 1]
```

This preserves the order of items in `l`.

Comment: That's O(N^2). I'm trying to solve it in linear time.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance then you need to be more specific about your situation, e.g. if the items in the list are always sorted, etc.

Comment: @NikhilRanjan people are trying to help here. Why should they have patience with you if you are not willing to do the same for them?

Comment: Looks like you think it is everybody's fault they can't guess what you want from your awesome question.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes that all you want to do is to create another list, only keeping the values that occur once.*

One way of doing it would be to use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools` and then filter based on the length of each group.

```
# Assuming 's' holds our list
[i for i,k in itertools.groupby(s) if len(list(k)) == 1]
```

**EDIT** Reading your question again, it seems this solution might not work, unless the linked list type you're using conforms to the iterator protocol. At any rate, it certainly won't produce a list as output, although you could replace the list comprehension with a generator expression and build a linked list from that.

Comment: It is hard to say what the OP wants: "autoarranging dict" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach in `O(n)` time (in Python 3), regardless of whether the list is sorted.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
>>> unique = {}
>>> for item in lst:
...     if item in unique:
...         unique[item] += 1
...     else:
...         unique[item] = 1
... 
>>> [k for k, v in unique.items() if v == 1]
[1, 2, 5]
```

- The statement `for item in lst: ...` is `O(n)`.

  - The expression `item in unique` is `O(1)`.
  - The statement `unique[item] = 1` is `O(1)`, and so is `unique[item] += 1`.
- The expression `[k for k, v in unique.items() if v == 1]` is `O(n)`.

So, calculating the time complexity of the `for` statement:

1. `O(n) * (O(1) + max(O(1), O(1)))`
2. `O(n) * (O(1) + O(1))`
3. `O(n) * O(1)`
4. `O(n)`

Add that to the time complexity of the list comprehension, and you have `O(n) + O(n)`, which is `O(2n)`. Drop the constant, and you have `O(n)`.